# Using factor vs. character and integer vs. double columns in dplyr/ggplot2

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am setting up a pipeline to import, format, normalize, and plot a bunch of datasets. The pipeline will rely heavily on tidyverse solutions (dplyr and ggplot2).

During the input/format step I would like to decide if/when to use factors vs. characters in various columns that contain letters. Likewise, I need to decide if I should designate numerical columns as integers (when it's reasonable) or use double.

My gut feeling is that as default I should just use character and double. Neither speed nor space are an issue since the resulting datasets are relatively small (~20 x 10,000 max) so I figure that this will give me the most flexibility. Are the disadvantages to going down this road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance shouldn't be a concern in most use case, the criterium is the meaning of the variables.

### Factor vs character

Use character if your data is just strings that do not hold specific meaning; use factor if it's a categorical variable with a limited set of values. The main advantages of using factors are:

1. you get an error if you try to give a new value that is not in the levels (so that can save you from typos)
2. you can give an order to the levels and get an ordered factor
3. some functions (especially when modelling) require an explicit factor for categorical variables
4. you make it clear to the reader that these are not random character strings.

### Integer vs double

If you know your column will only ever contain integer values, integer can be a better choice. Indeed, computations on doubles can give some numeric error, and in some situations you can end up with `26.0000000001 != 26`. In addition, some packages may be aware of the type of input (although I can't think of any example).

For big numbers (more than `2e31`), integers won't be able to store them whereas doubles will still behave correctly.

```
as.integer(2147483647)
#> [1] 2147483647
as.integer(2147483648)
#> [1] NA
#> Warning message:
#> NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

But when the numbers get even bigger, doubles will also start loosing significant digits:

```
1234578901234567890 == 1234578901234567891
#> [1] TRUE
```

Overall, I don't think there it makes a big difference in practice, using an integer type can be a way to signal to the reader and to the program that if there is a decimal number in that column, something went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for laying this out. I don't think the accuracy and large numbers are an issue, but I do like the enforcement of integers to avoid sneaking in transformations that give undesired results.

And yes, not overwriting and ordering the factors is another good thing to consider. So I believe that for my 'meta data' I will stick for factors and integers whenever I can.